# Tail -f last modified file in folder

Tags: linux, macos, unix, tail

I'm trying to use `tail -f` to follow a log in file in a specified folder. I can do this with the simple command `tail -f [path to file]` but is there a way i can have a command that runs and tracks the most recent/last modified file in a folder. Not an expert by any means in this area so any help much appreciated

Comment: Thanks. Just not sure how to combine that with `tail -f`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I've `cd` to the directory before running but it doesn't seem to update in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the `ls -tp | sort | grep -v / | tail -n 1` commands and put those through a [`for`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/forh.html) loop to then only run the `tail -F` command against the newest file to monitor it for content changes. You might also consider the `ls -tpr | grep -v / | tail -n 1` commands instead.

```
for VAR in $(ls -tp | sort | grep -v / | tail -n 1); do tail -F $VAR; done
```

or

```
for VAR in $(ls -tpr | grep -v / | tail -n 1); do tail -F $VAR; done
```

---

### Further Resources

- [`ls`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)

  > ```
  >    -t     sort by modification time, newest first
  >
  >    -p, --indicator-style=slash
  >           append / indicator to directories
  >
  >    -r, --reverse
  >           reverse order while sorting
  > ```
- [`sort`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)
- [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

  > ```
  > -v, --invert-match
  > Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX .)
  > ```
- [`tail`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

  > ```
  >   -n, --lines=[+]NUM
  >           output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n
  >           +NUM to output starting with line NUM
  > ```

Comment: @ChrisBarrett . . . you can likely eliminate the `sort` command from the command within the `for` loop and just use `ls -tpr | grep -v / | tail -n 1` instead to get the `ls` command to reverse the order of the date modified so you get the newest as expected without the additional sort from piped to `sort` command.

Comment: So....  `for VAR in $(ls -tpr | grep -v / | tail -n 1); do tail -F $VAR; done`

Comment: [Using `ls` in scripts is problematic,](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) though in this particular scenario the alternatives are pretty clunky, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
[MultiTail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/),
available as a standard package on many distributions.

**Example 1 : Merge two logfiles in one window with different colors**

```
multitail -ci green /var/log/yum.log -ci yellow -I /var/log/mysqld.log
```

[image]

**Example 2 : Display five logfiles, merging two in one column**

```
 multitail -s 2 -sn 1,3  /var/log/mysqld.log -I /var/log/xferlog /var/log/monitorix /var/log/ajenti.log /var/log/yum.log
```

[image]

Source:
[MultiTail – Monitor Multiple Files Simultaneously in a Single Linux Terminal](https://www.tecmint.com/view-multiple-files-in-linux/).

Comment: Thanks Harry but I'm looking for a solution that just uses the standard OSX packages.